# Find EMPTY Joomla content categories

Tags: joomla, joomla1.7

Did a Google search and couldn't come up with anything meaningful.

I have a ton of content categories, and want to unpublish the categories that **don't** have any content. (0 articles)

I am using J 1.7.3 and don't see a way to filter this in the backend.

Do I need to use an SQL query comparing jos_categories and jos_content? Unsure how I would do this either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you have direct access to your database?
If so, you can get a list of empty categories with a query like this:

```
SELECT id, title FROM #__categories WHERE id IN (SELECT DISTINCT catid FROM #__content)
```

Where you should replace the "#_" for your Joomla tables prefix (you will see it in the db, or you can see it in your configuration).
If you have no direct access to your database, maybe you can use the Joomla client to get the list, otherwise you should create a new component / module to do it, but I would take more unnecessary work if you just want this list once.

I hope it helped!

Comment: hey, thanks! I do have access to the database, but this SQL seems to show the categories that DO have articles in them. How do I find the articles that are empty?

Comment: Yes, sorry, it's been my mistake! Change the "id IN" for "id NOT IN" :)

Comment: Cool, seems to work, just added one slight tweak to filter to 'com_content' or else other categories show up too. THANKS MAN!


`SELECT id, title FROM j16_categories 
WHERE 
extension = 'com_content'
AND id NOT IN 
(SELECT DISTINCT catid FROM j16_content)`